# If I've deleted destiny do I keep my characters?

Tags: destiny

About 6 months ago I deleted destiny off of my ps4, I also deleted the cloud save. With the release of the taken king I have considered getting it again but I want to know if I will still have my character progress
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you do keep your characters as they are saved on Bungie's servers. You only keep some settings, cache and updates on your device.